# QGIS line cross a polygon

Tags: qgis

In QGIS I create a line that crosses a polygon twice. By using intersection, it will create a new shapefile that gives me as a result two visible lines (the polygon cut the line).

With geometry tool "from multiple part to single part" QGIS recognizes that I have two lines. The problem occurs when a line intersects itself because when I do the same procedure as above, QGIS thinks that I have four lines!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the **Multipart Split** plugin which you can download/enable from the menu bar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```

Then select the line feature and click the plugin icon:

[image: Before splitting]

Result:

[image: After splitting]

Comment: Yeah works but if the line interctions himself QGIS not recognize two line but more!

Comment: @lausent - Sorry, just to be clear: if the line intersects itself then you get more than 2 lines?

Comment: Exactly. Where the line intersects itself, I think that he must understand that is not true (like a line with an altitude in the point intersection)

Comment: @lausent - Try using the `Delete duplicate geometries` tool from the **Processing Toolbox**.

Comment: not work..ask for "point to keep" and "numeric attribute values". I have no idea of which is the point to keep...I mean I know that my line intersects itself but I don't know where....